# Flutter MySql select query not working with mysql1 package

Tags: mysql, flutter

I am new to Flutter and mysql. I wanted to create an app where the user will be prompted questions that are stored in a database. I established a connection using the mysql1 package in flutter. I know the connection is valid because the "insert into ..." statements work properly. However I can't pull any data from the database.

The following is the code block with the queries. The values inserted are dummy values just to test.

```
  String questionText = "";
  var db = MySql();

  void getData(String questionID) async {
    await db.getConnection().then((conn) async  {
      await conn.query("insert into questions values ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '2')");
      String qry = "select * from questions";
      await conn.query(qry).then((results) {
        print(results);
        if (results.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var row in results) {
          setState(() {
            questionText = row[0];
          });
        }
        } else {
          print("no data");
          questionText = "no data";
        }
        
      });
    });
  }
```

This function is called here:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData("1");
  }
```

and the db creation is done here:

```
class MySql {
  static String _host = "localhost",
                _user = "root",
                _password = "mypassword",
                _db = "mydb";
  static int _port = 3306;

  MySql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
      host:_host,
      port: _port,
      user: _user,
      password: _password,
      db: _db
    );

    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}
```

As I said, the insert statement inserts rows successfully but I can't get any data with select.

Comment: Is this code throwing any errors?

Comment: No, no errors. The app builds without a problem and questionText is set to "no data"

Comment: Could you please try this - `var results = await conn.query('select * from questions');
for (var row in results) {
 setState(() {
       questionText = row[0];
  });
}`

Comment: I tried that beforehand. It doesn't work as well. Again, the results variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `mysql1`'s async functions don't await properly. Meaning code continues to execute even though the awaited function hasn't completed.

If you do:

```
var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));          // add this
var results = await conn.query('select * from Foo');
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));          // add this
// handle results
```

The results are available for me.

I guess this is a bug or something. Either way it's very annoying.